# Write the integral $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{x}^{x\sqrt{3}}f(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})\,dy\,dx$ in polar coordinates with respect to $\theta$ first

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

I know how to to do this problem by writing the integral in polar coordinates with respect to $r$ *first* and $\theta$ *second*:

$$\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/3}\int_{0}^{1/\cos(\theta)}f(r)\,r\,dr\,d\theta,$$

but I've never seen an example of writing it with respect to $\theta$ first and $r$ second, so I'm unsure how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Aiming to use Fubini's theorem on the original integral, using the following picture (please excuse the bluriness, the lower triangle is labelled $D_1$ and the upper, smaller one is labelled $D_2$) I have that $D_1=\{y/\sqrt{3}\leq x\leq y,\,\,0\leq y\leq ?\}$ and $D_2=\{y/\sqrt{3}\leq x\leq 1,\,\,?\leq y\leq \sqrt{3}\}$. How do I figure out the value of $y$ at the blue line? And once I've determined this, how does this help with the original question?

[image]

Comment: use fubini's theorem to switch order of integration perhaps

Comment: @Goldname Hey thanks for the reply. I know how to apply Fubini's theorem in Cartesian coordinates with $dy$ and $dx$, but I wouldn't know how to attempt it in polar coordinates, because I'm not sure how I'd write the limits on the inner/first integral to be functions of $r$, and the limits on the outer integral to be constants of $r$.

Comment: @Goldname Please also see my edit.

Comment: Which area are you trying to figure out? Also the picture is unclear. There should be some given angles for those triangles.

Comment: @Goldname The region $D=D_1\cup D_2$ is what we're integrating over and there are no angles given in the diagram, but I guess it can be worked out by the equations of the lines $y=x$ and $y=x\sqrt{3}$, hence my choice of $\theta=\pi/4$ and $\theta=\pi/2$ in the integral that is with respect to $\theta$ second. I'm stuck as to how to proceed once using Fubini's theorem (for which I also don't know the height of $y$ at the blue line).

Answer (score 0):

The representation of the triangles $D_{1}$ and $D_{2}$ is not necessary to switch the order of the polar coordinates, especially because triangles aren't too nice in polar. We can work mainly from your iterated integral $$\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/3}\int_{0}^{1/\cos\theta}f\left(r\right)r\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\theta\text{.}$$

To integrate with respect to $r$ second, we need the absolute bounds for $r$. Since $r$ can start at $0$ in the iterated integral and $1/\cos\theta$ is positive for $\pi/4\le\theta\le\pi/3$, the minimum value of $r$ is $0$. The highest value of $r$ is when $1/\cos\theta$ is maximized, which is when $\cos\theta$ is minimized, at $\theta=\pi/3$ so $r=1/\cos\left(\pi/3\right)=2$. (We could also have seen this in your diagram with $\left(1,\sqrt{3}\right)$ being furthest from the origin, at distance $2$.) Our new iterated integral will look something like $$\int_{0}^{2}\int_{\theta_{1}\left(r\right)}^{\theta_{2}\left(r\right)}f\left(r\right)r\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}r\text{.}$$

We now need to find the bounds for $\theta$ in terms of $r$. Rather than splitting the region into two triangles $D_{1}$ and $D_{2}$, it's helpful to break up the region into a sector $A_{1}$ and the remainder $A_{2}$ (image created with Desmos):

[image: the lines x=1, theta=pi/4, theta=pi/3, and an arc of a circle centered at the origin passing through the point (1,1), with sector labeled A1 and the region above the circle but within the lines labeled A2]

When $r$ is small, as in, less than $\sqrt{2}$, $\theta$ can range from $\pi/4$ to $\pi/3$. But when $r$ is larger than $\sqrt{2}$, the vertical line $x=1$ restricts $\theta$, and so we must solve $r=1/\cos\theta$ to find $\theta=\arccos\left(1/r\right)$ as the minimum value, and $\pi/3$ is still the maximum. Even without the image above, we could have seen this split algebraically by noting that when $r<\sqrt{2}$, $\arccos\left(1/r\right)<\pi/4$, so that the boundary $r=1/\cos\theta$ does not constrain the original range for $\theta$ of $\left[\pi/4,\pi/3\right]$.

Either way, we have:
$$\int_{0}^{2}\int_{\max\left(\pi/4,\arccos(1/r)\right)}^{\pi/3}f\left(r\right)r\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}r$$
$$=\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/3}f\left(r\right)r\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}r+\int_{\sqrt{2}}^{2}\int_{\arccos(1/r)}^{\pi/3}f\left(r\right)r\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}r\text{.}$$